# How to use Phalcon ORM for deleting a result set

Tags: php, orm, phalcon

Consider the following code form document

```
foreach (Robots::find("type='mechanical'") as $robot) {
    if ($robot->delete() == false) {
        echo "Sorry, we can't delete the robot right now: \n";
        foreach ($robot->getMessages() as $message) {
            echo $message, "\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "The robot was deleted successfully!";
    }
}
```

Using Phalcon, is it possible to delete a result set with a single operation (without iteration).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Resultset.html) `delete()` deletes every record in the resultset.

```
$robots = Robots::find("type='mechanical'");

if($robots->delete()){
    echo "The robots were deleted successfully!";
}
```

Comment: I wanna know whether deleting record with this way would run SQL twice ? once for SELECT and another for DELETE

Comment: @LCB If you look at the source you can see that Phalcon creates a transaction then calls `delete` on every object in the `resultset`, it only commits the transaction when every record is deleted.